# error while running "flutter doctor --android-licenses"

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class Pandey\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Pandey\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\//
```

I got this error after installing android SDK command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

> It means your java is not installed or not the correct version

Install [Java SE 16](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html) and set the [PATH variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-E3C75F92-D3B2-421D-A9BE-933C15F7CD1B) [In Windows].

- After installing and setting up the path properly, run the `C:\Users\__\local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager –update` command in the new terminal and it will work.
- Rerun flutter doctor, You can see it says to run the command `flutter doctor –android-licenses`. so run `flutter doctor –android-licenses` in the terminal and press `y` when asked

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android studio open SDK manager and install the "Android SDK command-line tool" or update if it's not.

*This should solve the problem